# How can I split a column across pages in PDF export?

Tags: export, pdf-format, pagelayout

Suppose I have two cells.  The first cell is styled with "Section", and has contents "Section".  The second cell is

```
Column[Table[StringJoin["a", ToString[n]], {n, 0, 50}]] // TraditionalForm
```

and the evaluation of that.

When I click Save As, and save this notebook as a .pdf file, I get the following page split:

First page:

[image: first page]

Second page:

[image: second page]

The full notebook file is available at https://gist.github.com/JasonGross/f8fa30c1488ea4c42a53b90dc86fccd9

---

I would like instead to have the column be split in the middle.  This happens automatically with, e.g.,

```
Column[Table[StringJoin["a", ToString[n]], {n, 0, 100}]] // TraditionalForm
```

How do I tell Mathematica that is is free to split columns across pages?